# Using Remodal JS with a Gallery in Expression Engine

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, expressionengine

Hope someone out there can possibly help - I'm using Expression Engine as the platform, and I am using Remodal (as a modal) to work alongside a gallery. The gallery page consists of multiple images in a masonry-style format, and what I am wanting is basically when the user clicks an image, the Remodal popup kicks in and shows the image in the popup. With the code below, the popup functionality is working no problem, however, the issue is, what ever image on the page you click, the first image and title displays in the popup, and not the image you expect to see (the one you click on).

From what I understand, I need to now use some Javascript in order to popup the image you click on, but I am no good at Javascript to be honest, so any help would be great.

This is the modal HTML:

> 

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="gallery"
    dynamic="off"
    limit="1"
    url_title="{segment_3}"
}

<img src="{cf_gallery_image}" alt="{title}" />

<div class="gallery__title">{title}</div>
{if cf_gallery_copy != ""}
    <div class="gallery__subtitle">{cf_gallery_copy}</div>
{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

So when you click any image on the gallery page, the code above displays a popup but of the first image on the page only, and not the image you expect to see.

The gallery HTML:

> {exp:ce_img:pair
>                           src="{cf_gallery_image}"
>                           fallback_src="static/images/fabric-no-image.png"
>                           width="360"
>                           crop="no"
>                       }
>                           
>                       {/exp:ce_img:pair}

Thank you.
Mike

Comment: Looks like the gallery link matches the modal via either an id or data-remodal-target.  Your sample code does not show either of these values.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I think I described the issue wrong. Basically with the below Javascript, I'm wanting to link to the gallery item but I think must have coded this wrong, I'll admit that JS is my weakest point.

Comment: $(document).on('opening', '.remodal', function () {
   console.log('Modal is opening');
   console.log($(this));
   console.log($(this).html("gallery__item"));
 });